# Adding tooltips to circles from an array with D3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I'm trying to add tooltips to the circles as in [**this example**](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). Here is my [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/L12jdEe9RKOLD4yDrlSo?p=preview).

I'm trying to show the array values on tooltip in this method but tooltips doesn't appear on the graph:

```
function plotMeans(){
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle.means")
            .data(numeric.transpose([x_means, y_means]));

    var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function() {
                    return "<strong>Means:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + [x_means, y_means] + "</span>";
            });

    svg.call(tip);

    circle.enter().append("circle")
            .attr('class', 'means')
            .attr("r", 10)
            .on("mouseover", tip.show)
            .on("mouseover", tip.hide);

    circle
            .transition().ease("linear").duration(200)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return X(d[0]); })
            .attr("cy", function(d, i){return Y(d[1]);});


    circle.exit().remove();
}
```

Any ideas on how to show tooltips on graph with `[x_means, y_means]` values?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I have [**this visualisation**](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) and I want to show tooltips on the red circles.

```
function plotMeans(){
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle.means")
            .data(numeric.transpose([x_means, y_means]));

    console.log(numeric.transpose([x_means, y_means])); //returns 3 pairs of X-Y values

    var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function() {
                for(var i = 0; i < k; i++){
                    return "<strong>Means:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + JSON.stringify(meansjson) + "</span>";
                }

            });

    svg.call(tip);

    circle.enter().append("circle")
            .attr('class', 'means')
            .attr("r", 10)
            .on("mouseover", tip.show)
            .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

    circle
            .transition().ease("linear").duration(200)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return X(d[0]); })
            .attr("cy", function(d, i){return Y(d[1]);});


    circle.exit().remove();
}
```

I want to display the X and Y values of red circles with tooltips. `console.log(numeric.transpose([x_means, y_means]));` returns three pairs of X-Y values but I don't know how to correctly display these values on the red dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is cool. You made a tiny mistake:

When mouse is over the circle, you want to show the tooltip, and when mouse pointer is off, you want to hide it. So if you change the following lines:

```
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseover", tip.hide);
```

to:

```
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", tip.hide);
```

it works.

**__update__**

simply add this function

```
function average(dataArray){
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0; i< dataArray.length; i++){
    sum=sum+dataArray[i];
  }
  return sum/dataArray.length;
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
return "<strong>Means:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + [average(x_means), average(y_means)] + "</span>";
```

Comment: @supaplex doesn't it do what you want ?

Comment: Yes, it solves half of the problem, thanks @Alp But, it shows all of the x_means and y_means values. I need to figure out how to display the only one pair of x and y values.

Comment: @supaplex Updated my answer. But I am not sure if my solution for showing the correct pair of coordinates is really what you want.

Comment: @supaplex where is meansjson defined  in your update ?

Comment: I found a solution by adding function(d) argument. Thank you for your help!